# Flutter - multiply the values ​from different text fields

Tags: flutter, textfield

I need your help please,

I want to multiply the values ​​from different text fields. I am facing the problem that `*` cant be used with `TexteditingController()` in:

```
void _calculation() {
    _volume = lenCon * widCon * higCon;
    print(_volume);
  }
```

Do I need to transfrom my Variables like `lenCon` to double before? How can I do that? `var lenConInt = double.parse(lenCon);` doesnt work.

The RaisedButton must execute `_calculation` and change the Text with the proper Value. Do I need a StatlessWidget for that or SetState?

Thanks in Advance!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _volume = 0;

//  var _lenght;
//  var _width;
//  var _hight;

  void _calculation() {
    _volume = lenCon * widCon * higCon;
    print(_volume);
  }

  final lenCon = new TextEditingController();
  final widCon = new TextEditingController();
  final higCon = new TextEditingController();

  // var lenConInt = double.parse(lenCon);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: lenCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Länge',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: widCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Breite',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: higCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Höhe',
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (_calculation),
                child: Text('Berechnen'),
              ),
              Text('Your Volume is: $_volume'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try `var lenConDouble = double.parse(lenCon.text);` 
`.text` retreives the entered value from the TextEditingController
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

Comment: I advise you to read about differences between Stateless Widget and Stateful Widget ;)

Comment: @sonic the use of a stateful widget here is correct because of the last Text widget he wants to update after calculation. However, the state is not initialized correctly.

Comment: @Heikkisorsa I am not saying that using stateful widget is mistake here. Im just pointing to the question "Do I need a StatlessWidget for that or SetState?"  Im about to answer: "answer yourself what do you really need to use and why"

Comment: @sonic you are right, i have to learn a lot!

Comment: @SiggiSmilez mee tooo !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in order to get it functional:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _volume;

  @override
  initState(){
      _volume = 0;
  }

  void _calculation() {
    setState((){
        _volume = int.parse(lenCon.text) * int.parse(widCon.text) * int.parse(higCon.text);
        },
    );
    print(_volume);
  }

  final lenCon = TextEditingController();
  final widCon = TextEditingController();
  final higCon = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: lenCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Länge',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: widCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Breite',
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: higCon,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Höhe',
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (_calculation),
                child: Text('Berechnen'),
              ),
              Text('Your Volume is: $_volume'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

First, you need some type of conversion between string and integers (or even double if you want). Second, you should put the resulting `_volume` in a state so that the UI refreshes when you update the state (via `setState`). Try to avoid `var` and use concrete types instead. It will help you in the long-run.

Comment: this was an "Aha" moment. I need to put SetState into the _calculation Function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The variables `lenCon`, `widCon` and `higCon` are of type `TextEditingConroller`. The `TextEditingController` is a class that will help you control the information in the `TextField`.

In this case you'd probably want to access the value the user inputted into the `TextField` which you'd be able to access using the `text` property of the `TextEditorController`. If you'd update your `calculation` method to something like below it should work:

```dart
void _calculation() {
  final length = double.parse(lenCon.text);
  final width = double.parse(widCon.text);
  final height = double.parse(higCon.text);

  _volume = length * width * height;
  print(_volume);
}
```

You still need to use the `double.parse` since the `.text` property will return a `String` which needs to be converted to something you make calculations on (a numeric value type).

As mentioned the `TextEditingController` will give you access to more information about the user's interaction with the `TextField`. For example the selected part of the text (using the `selection` property). If you would like to read up you could check out: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maurits van Beusekom I was able to get the calculation done.

But I had to move it to the Button to make the `Text('Your Volume is: $_volume'),` working.

```
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            final length = double.parse(lenCon.text);
            final width = double.parse(widCon.text);
            final height = double.parse(higCon.text);

            _volume = length * width * height;
            print(_volume);
          });
        },
        child: Text('Berechnen'),
      ),
```

Edit:

Nevermind, I just have to put the SetState into the calculation.